# How do you insert line breaks in strings and translations string to meet the PEP 8 requirements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython, translation

I try to write Python code that fits the PEP8 requirements. The PEP8 code style guide says that code lines in Python should not be longer than 79 characters. In my code I have a lot of long strings like:

```
string_name = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam"
```

And I have a lot of long translations strings like:

```
string_name = _("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam")
```

I searched for the best and fastest way to break those strings but I did not found a answer that satisfied me. For example I know that I can insert breaks by hand like this:

```
string_name = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, " \
"sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna " \
"aliquyam"
```

But this is very unhandy. For example if I add a word in the first part of the string, I have to rewrite all the rest.

I am searching for a better option or a module that can do this for me.

I hope you can help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
import textwrap

def pep8_textwrap(var_name, text, parentheses=False):
    '''Wrap text for code to be within 80 characters.'''

    # Variable name appended with assignment operator.
    var_name += ' = '

    if parentheses:
        var_name += '('

    # Indent size to align with right side of assignment.
    indent_size = len(var_name) - 1

    # Create a list of wrapped text.
    string_list = textwrap.wrap(text, width=75-indent_size)

    # Print the variable name equals without a newline.
    print(var_name, end='')

    # The last line so end of iteration will be known.
    last_line = len(string_list)

    # Print the wrapped text for pasting into code.
    for current_line, line in enumerate(string_list, 1):
        if current_line == 1:
            if last_line > 1 and not parentheses:
                print(repr(line + ' '), '\\')
            else:
                print(repr(line + ' '))
        elif current_line >= last_line:
            if parentheses:
                print(indent_size * ' ', repr(line) + ')')
            else:
                print(indent_size * ' ', repr(line))
        else:
            if parentheses:
                print(indent_size * ' ', repr(line + ' '))
            else:
                print(indent_size * ' ', repr(line + ' '), '\\')


# Text from 1st code example.
string_name = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam"

# Call the function to print the result.
pep8_textwrap('string_name', string_name)

# Text from 3rd code example.
string_name = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, " \
"sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna " \
"aliquyam"

pep8_textwrap('string_name', string_name, True)

# Text from the title.
string_name = "How do you insert line breaks in strings and translations string to meet the PEP 8 requirements?"

pep8_textwrap('var', string_name, True)
```

A scripted solution to recreate the assignment code.
It will print the result to stdout.

Copy the assignment into the script and call `pep8_textwrap` with the parameters
of variable name to assign to, the actual variable name for the text and
optionally `True` for use parentheses or omit that parameter for use of backslash
escape to continue a line to the next line.

Output:

> ```
> string_name = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed ' \
>               'diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna ' \
>               'aliquyam'
> string_name = ('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed '
>                'diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna '
>                'aliquyam')
> var = ('How do you insert line breaks in strings and translations string to '
>        'meet the PEP 8 requirements?')
> ```

Answer (score 0):

That should do the thing:

```
string_name = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet," \
"consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy" \
"eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam"
```

Comment: This is a option I know. Sorry, I should have written this in my question. But this option is very unhandy. For example if you add a word in the first part of the string you have rewrite all the rest by hand. I am searching for a better option. I edited my question.